# I want to disable IPv6 to install Hadoop 2.7.1, but doesn't work

Tags: hadoop, ipv6

I am installing hadoop 2.7.1 .

It was written there:

"Disable IPv6 with the command
`sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf`
and copy the following lines at the end of the file:

```
#disable ipv6  
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1  
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1   
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Use the command     `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6`    to check to make sure IPv6 is off:
it should say 1. If it says 0, you missed something."

After using      `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6`     command I am getting "0". that means it don't get disable.
What i am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you run `sysctl -p` after editing the file to activate the changes?

Answer (score 0):

> sudo apt-get install gksu
>
> gksu gedit /etc/sysctl.conf

If you’re set on using terminal then this’ll do it:

> echo "net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1" | sudo tee -a
>   /etc/sysctl.conf
>
> echo "net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1" | sudo tee -a
>   /etc/sysctl.conf
>
> echo "net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1" | sudo tee -a
>   /etc/sysctl.conf

at this point you can try to run

> sudo service networking restart

However, Atheros and Ubuntu seem to have a strange sort of ‘not working’ thing going on and so that command doesn’t work with my wireless driver. If the restart fails, just restart the computer and you should be good.

(if you’re terminal only : sudo shutdown -r now )

Has it worked up to here?

If you’re stout of heart, attempt the following:

> su - hduser 
>   ssh localhost

If that’s worked you be greeted with a message along the lines of ‘Are you sure you want to continue connecting?’ The answer you’re looking for at this point is ‘yes’.

If it hasn’t worked at this point run the following command:

> cat /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/disable_ipv6

If the value returned is 0 then you’ve still not got ipv6 disabled – have a re-read of that section and see if you’ve missed anything.